# Symfony validation with dynamic message

Tags: validation, symfony, propel

I have been looking around and was wondering if it is possible to validate a form but dynamically add error message.

For example:

```
Test\TesterBundle\Model\Products:
    constraints:
        - Propel\PropelBundle\Validator\Constraints\UniqueObject:
            fields: [Url, SKU, Title]
            message: Field already exists
```

This if the Url isn't unique it will output Field already Exists. However, it doesn't state which field already exists.

My first thought was to use [fields] inside the message which through an error:

```
Test\TesterBundle\Model\Products:
    constraints:
        - Propel\PropelBundle\Validator\Constraints\UniqueObject:
            fields: [Url, SKU, Title]
            message: [fields] already exists
```

I then tried a simple %s to see if it already inserted this but just output the string.

Is there an already created method, would I need to extend the UniqueObject Constraint and create a new one that outputs the field name aswel, or would I need to create a new function to do this?

Comment: try : `{{ value }} already exists`

Comment: @StivenLlupa I didn't think it would work but as this is validation.yml file it instantly brings up an error:

Unexpected characters near "} Already Exists" at line 20 (near "message: {{ value }} Already Exists")

Comment: I am using this format on my validation file, but it is related to one field not multiple

Comment: Are you using YML as well? Or do you have the message in quotes?

Comment: Yes using YML and full sentence is "{{ value }} is not a valid email."